# Configuring ACS Programmatically

Tags: azure, acs

Simple question - is there anything that we can use to programmatically configure ACS using PowerShell (or some other command line tool)? It looks like the old CodePlex build of the PowerShell cmdlets supported this but the later official builds don't seem to have anything available.

Comment: There are code samples for accessing ACS using OData, I'm trying to avoid writing something from scratch... If there's nothing out there I guess I can always setup a repository on GitHub with the result of my efforts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways you can interact with ACS:

- Directly with the management service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh135143.aspx
- By using the FluentACS library: https://github.com/jrowies/FluentACS/blob/master/README.markdown
- By using the **old** PowerShell cmdlets: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2011/05/18/manage-windows-azure-appfabric-access-control-service-acs-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: That's perfect, FluentACS looks the way to go for us. Thanks!

Comment: **FluentACS** was a good staring point - wraps up the existing ACS Management API using command-style interfaces, built-in logging, and parameter validation. We extended it to support our needs rather than starting from ground zero.